# Claves expuestas del servidor Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: java, android, push-notification

Buen día a todos, recientemente he tenido un problema con mi aplicación en la Play Store, Google la ha estado removiendo porque la clave esta expuesta, este el el mensaje que recibo cada vez que remueven mi app:

Problema con tu aplicación
Descubrimos que su aplicación contiene vulnerabilidades de seguridad, que pueden exponer la información del usuario o dañar el dispositivo de un usuario. Esta es una violación de la política de abuso de dispositivos y redes. Específicamente, sus aplicaciones son vulnerables a las **claves expuestas del servidor Firebase Cloud Messaging**. Para solucionar este problema, siga los pasos de este artículo del *Centro de ayuda de Googl*e.

Ahora que ya sabemos cual es el problema procederé a mostrar mi código con el cual envió notificaciones a los usuarios:

```
public void sendNotification(){

    RequestQueue myrequest= Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    try {

        json.put("to", TicketDatos.token); //Aqui el envio se hace al usuario que esta haciendo el proceso del pedido 
        JSONObject notificacion=new JSONObject();
        notificacion.put("titulo", "¡Hay un nuevo pedido!");
        notificacion.put("detalle","Revisa tus pedidos activos para procesar el nuevo pedido");
        notificacion.put("click_action", "NUEVOPEDIDO");
        notificacion.put("id_cliente", Login.gIdCliente);
        notificacion.put("nombre_cliente", Login.nombre);

        json.put("data",notificacion);
        String URL= "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
        JsonObjectRequest request=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,URL,json,null,null){
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                Map<String,String>header=new HashMap<>();
                header.put("content-type","application/json");
                header.put("authorization", DatosPrincipales.serverKey); //En esta parte es donde agrego la clave del servidor de firebase al principio tenia directamente la clave pero ahora la obtengo de la base de datos sin embargo el problema persiste

                return header;

            }
        };
        myrequest.add(request);


    }catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Cuando estaba aprendiendo esto de las notificaciones ya me habían advertido sobre esto que el código se debe ejecutar desde el servidor y no desde la app sin embargo mi poco conocimiento me llevo a utilizar esta forma para enviar notificaciones a los usuarios debido a que se adapta perfectamente a lo que necesitaba y de hecho siempre me había funcionado de maravilla pero lastimosamente hay una fuga de seguridad!!!

Entonces como puedo seguir utilizando este método sin obtener este problema, realmente necesito ejecutar este código dentro de la app cuando los usuarios finalizan un pedido y no he encontrado otra forma de hacerlo, si necesitan mas código o mas explicación por favor hacérmelo saber de antemano muchas gracias por la ayuda!!!

Answer (score 0):

El problema, como comentas, se encuentra aquí, ya que el valor de `serverKey` que es tu API Key, puede ser obtenido por ingeniería inversa.

```
header.put("authorization", DatosPrincipales.serverKey);
```

Dentro de tu archivo build.gradle debes agregar:

```
    classpath "com.google.android:secrets-gradle-plugin:1.1.0"
```

dentro de `app/build.gradle` :

```
apply plugin: "com.google.android.secrets-gradle-plugin"
```

dentro de tu archivo `local.properties` agrega el valor de tu API KEY, por ejemplo:

```
FIREBASE_API_KEY=AIzaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

y dentro de tu AndroidManifest.xml agrega un metadato haciendo referencia a este valor:

```
    <meta-data
        android:name = "firebaseApiKey"
        android:value = "${FIREBASE_API_KEY}"/>
</application>
```

Para obtener el valor de la API Key, crea un método el cual llamarías en tu código para obtener este valor.

```
public String getFirebaseAPIKEY(Context context){
    String apiKey = "";
    try {
        ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        apiKey = applicationInfo.metaData.getString("firebaseApiKey");
    }catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

    }
    return apiKey;
}
```